# Obtaining a bound for the Jacobian in a change of variables.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a diffeomorphism which I will use to make a change of variables for an integral for which I have to obtain an upper bound. The definition of the diffeomorphism $H$ is defined as follows (This is the definition given in *Haim Brezis' Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* for an open set $\Omega$ of class $C^1$):

> We define the following sets:
>
> - $R_+ = \{x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x_n \geq 0\} $
>
>   - $ Q = \{x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i^2)^{1/2} < 1 \ y \  |x_n|<1 \}$
>   - $ Q_+=R_+ \cap Q $
>   - $ Q_0=\{(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ (\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i^2)^{1/2} < 1 \}$
>
> An open set $\Omega$ is of class $C^1$ if for every $x \in \partial \Omega$ there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
>   a bijective map $H: Q \to U_x$ such that:
>
> - $H \in C^1(\overline{Q})$
> - $H^{-1} \in C^1(\overline{U_x})$
> - $H(Q_+)=U_x \cap Q$
> - $H(Q_0)= U_x \cap \partial \Omega$

Suppose also that I have been able to prove that: $$\int_{Q_0} f(y) dy \leq C \varphi(y)$$

And that I have a definite integral: $$\int_{ U_x \ \cap \ \partial \Omega} f(x) dx $$
Which I want to transform via $H_x$ into: $$\int_{Q_0} f(H(y)) \ |Jac(H)| \ dy$$

Is there anyway I can conclude: $$\int_{Q_0} f(H(y)) \ |Jac(H)| \ dy \leq \tilde{C} \varphi (y)$$